# Angularjs-Spring : Getting parameter as Null in controller

Tags: java, angularjs, spring

Here is the code for the controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/fetchRecord/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String fetchRecord(Integer primaryKey)
    {
        return this.serviceClass.fetchRecord(primaryKey);
    }
```

Here is my angular code

```
var dataObj = {
            primaryKey : $scope.primaryKey
        };
        var res = $http.post('/Practice/learn/fetchRecord/', dataObj);
        res.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

            $scope.firstname = data;
        });
        res.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

            alert("failure message: " + JSON.stringify({
                data : data
            }));
        });
```

i am able to debug my code. Although i can check it in browser that value for primaryKey get passed. But still it is null in controller.

any possible reason for that ?

Comment: You may try fetchrecord(@Requestbody Integer primkey)

Comment: facing error : The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

Comment: And $http.put instead of post

Comment: HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'PUT' not supported

Comment: change it in controller also .. now again facing : The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect

Comment: Value = "/fetchRecord/{yourobject}", method = .....

Comment: but what if i want to send it as POST

Answer (score 0):

You should send a json object,

try this,

```
var dataObj = {
            primaryKey : $scope.primaryKey
};
var res = $http.post('/Practice/learn/fetchRecord/', angular.toJson(dataObj));
```

Comment: still it is Null :(

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value in the `Controller` from two ways:

*First option:*

Assign an object that has the attribute you want to pass.
Suppose that you have `RecordEntity` object, it has some attributes, one of them is the `Integer primaryKey`. The annotation `@RequestBody` will receive the value, so the controller will be:

**backend**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/fetchRecord/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String fetchRecord(@RequestBody RecordEntity recordEntity) {
    return "primaryKey from requestBody: " +  recordEntity.getPrimaryKey();
}
```

**frontend**

In the frontend you should send an `json` that has the `primaryKey` attribute in the body, for example:

```
http://localhost:8080/Practice/learn/fetchRecord/
```

*Post body:*

```
{
    "primaryKey": 123
}
```

You controller will receive the value in the `RecordEntity` object.

---

*Second option:*

Pass the value by URL, the annotation `@RequestParam` will receive the value, so the controller will be:

**backend**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/fetchRecord", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String fetchRecord(@RequestParam Integer primaryKey) {
    return "primaryKey from RequestParam: " +  primaryKey;
}
```

**frontend**

In the url you should send the value with `?primaryKey`, for example

```
http://localhost:8080/Practice/learn/fetchRecord?primaryKey=123
```

You controller will receive the value in the `Integer primaryKey`.